# Regex for htaccess not deflate specific files

Tags: regex

In this code, it match any css, js, html, php file and enable the deflate...

```
# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
<filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files
```

The Regex is `\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$`

I'd like to do an exception... if the file name is core or loader, it simple dont deflat... what's the Regex for that?

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the exception for `core` and `loader` by using [Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So, the following *regex* should work :

`(?<!core)(?<!loader)\.(css|js|x|html|php)$`

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you so much!!